# Oracle SQL 3 Level Structure from a single table

Tags: sql, oracle, data-structures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table `STRUCTURE` which contains the following data when queried with:

```
SELECT *
FROM STRUCTURE
WHERE structure_id = 'LOCA'

structure_id    name_value  description     level_no    item_above  structure_item_type_db  Level_id    level_description
LOCA            3000        North           4           300         1                       4           Area
LOCA            827         North A         4           3000        2                       4           Area
LOCA            828         North 1         4           3000        2                       4           Area
LOCA            829         North 2         4           3000        2                       4           Area
LOCA            830         North 3         4           3000        2                       4           Area
LOCA            300         North & South   3           LOCA        1                       3           Area Group
LOCA            3010        North Other     4           300         1                       4           Area
LOCA            879         North Other     4           3010        2                       4           Area
```

I have this code to get 2 Levels (Description and Area_Group) but I cannot get the 3rd level.

```
WITH CTE(NAME_VALUE, ITEM_ABOVE, DESCRIPTION, Area_Group) AS 
(
   SELECT NAME_VALUE, ITEM_ABOVE, DESCRIPTION, DESCRIPTION AS Area_Group
   FROM STRUCTURE
   WHERE ITEM_ABOVE = 'LOCA' AND Structure_id = 'LOCA'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t1.NAME_VALUE, t1.ITEM_ABOVE, t1.DESCRIPTION, t2.Area_Group
   FROM STRUCTURE t1
   JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.ITEM_ABOVE = t2.NAME_VALUE
   WHERE  Structure_id = 'LOCA'
)
SELECT DESCRIPTION, Area_Group
FROM CTE
```

Gives me:

```
description     Area_Group
North           North & South
North A         North & South
North 1         North & South
North 2         North & South
North 3         North & South
North & South   North & South
North Other     North & South
North Other     North & South
```

I want to output the data (`WHERE structure_id = 'LOCA'` is needed as there are other structures that aren't used in this scenario) to look like this:

```
description     Area_Group      Area
North           North & South   North
North A         North & South   North
North 1         North & South   North
North 2         North & South   North
North 3         North & South   North
North & South   North & South   North
North Other     North & South   North Other
North Other     North & South   North Other
```

So if we imagine the structure as a tree structure...

```
Area_Group - North & South
     └ Area - North
         └ description - North A
           description - North 1
           description - North 2
           description - North 3
     └ Area - North Other
         └ description - North Other
```

Comment: Where are `Area Group` and `Area` defined?  Your question is not very clear.

Comment: In the `level_description` field, let me add some more context for my expected output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added a tree structure for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help, two self-joins and `CASE WHEN` statements:

```
WITH
  sa AS (SELECT * 
         FROM structure 
         WHERE structure_id = 'LOCA'),
  sb AS (SELECT s1.description, s1.name_value, s1.level_id,
         CASE WHEN s1.structure_item_type_db = 1
              THEN s1.description 
              ELSE s2.description
         END area,
         CASE WHEN s1.structure_item_type_db = 1
              THEN s1.item_above 
              ELSE s2.item_above
         END item_above
         FROM sa s1 
         LEFT JOIN sa s2 ON s2.name_value = s1.item_above)
         SELECT s1.description, 
         CASE WHEN s1.level_id = 3 
              THEN s1.description 
              ELSE s2.description 
         END area_group, s1.area
         FROM sb s1 
         LEFT JOIN sb s2 ON s2.name_value = s1.item_above
```

<sup>**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2df14/1)**</sup>

In your data, in row 6 `item_above` has value 3500, and there is no row with such `name_value`, so `left join` attaches nothing here. Column `ID` added only for presentation purposes.

Output:

```
   DESCRIPTION     AREA_GROUP      AREA
 --------------- --------------- ---------------
   North           North & South   North
   North A         North & South   North
   North 1         North & South   North
   North 2         North & South   North
   North 3         North & South   North         
   North & South   North & South   North & South
   North Other     North & South   North Other
   North Other     North & South   North Other
```

Comment: What about hierarchical Query?

Comment: @Jigar - Hierarchical query is the alternative, especially when number of sub-levels is unknown. You could post such a query as new answer. For 3 levels I would stay at self-join solution or maybe modified query based on analytic functions.